# How to stop MySQL queries on user abort?

Tags: php, mysql

#### The problem

I've got a large query which I want to be terminated as soon as the user aborts. I've searched and came across the following questions:

- [Kill MySQL query on user abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582485/kill-mysql-query-on-user-abort)
- [KILL MySQL queries using PHP if user close the browser or navigate from one page to other page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044173/kill-mysql-queries-using-php-if-user-close-the-browser-or-navigate-from-one-page)
- [Killing a MySQL query during execution with PHP and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077995/killing-a-mysql-query-during-execution-with-php-and-ajax)

From these questions I substracted the usefull parts which resulted in the code below.

#### Code

```
// Connection to query on
$query_con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $name);

// Connection to kill on
$kill_con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $name);

$slow_query = "...";

// Start the query
$query_con->query($slow_query, MYSQLI_ASYNC);

// Get the PID
$thread_id = $query_con->thread_id;

// Ignore user abort so we can kill the query
ignore_user_abort(true);

do  {
    // Poll MySQL
    $links = $errors = $reject = array($mysqli->mysqli);
    $poll = mysqli_poll($links, $errors, $reject, 0, 500000);

    // Check if the connection is aborted and the query was killed
    if (connection_aborted() && mysqli_kill($kill_con, $thread_id)) {
        die();
    }
} while (!$poll);

// Not aborted, so do stuff with the result
$result = $link->reap_async_query();
if (is_object($result)) {
    // Select
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $articles[] = $row;
    }
}

echo count($articles);
```

#### Errors

The above code throws me the following errors:

- Notice: Use of undefined constant MYSQLI_ASYNC - assumed 'MYSQLI_ASYNC'
- Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given
- Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli
- Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
- Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_poll()

#### Question

I am really stuck here and do not know how to go forward from this point.

Comment: FIX YOUR CODE .. all Errors and Notices are self explained! For more information use php.net to use the methods / functions correctly

Comment: Where did you get this code? If you have an undefined variable, then you need to define it. Can you also explain your general strategy? How do you intend to run PHP code if your code is waiting for a slow query to return?

Comment: @halfer I found this code in an answer to a similiar question I listed above.